# Does network interface device have device inodes

Tags: linux, devices

Does network devices have device nodes because i have looked inside /dev directory and have not found any corresponding device node although it's up and running

Answer (score 1):

Not on Linux. Network communication in Linux is socket-based, having a device node would serve no purpose.

Some other Unix flavours may have an entry in `/dev` for the interface (e.g. I know that SCO Unix did).